# redirect awk exec results to another folder

Tags: bash, awk, io-redirection, exec

Trying to capitalize the content of the files that match the filename pattern "_base.txt"; then output the results to another folder with the original filename plus the "_cap.txt" in the end.

I plan to do this through 3,000 files. So I am testing it on a few files at the moment.

First I was able to get the content capitalized. But all output results were not redirected.

```
BASE="/home/dir/input/"
find "$BASE" -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec awk '{print toupper($0)}' {} +
```

Then I added the following, which allowed me to output to a new filename ended with "_cap.txt"

```
BASE="/home/dir/input/"
find "$BASE" -type f -iname "*_pv_bind_basefile.txt" -exec awk '{print toupper($0) >> (FILENAME "_cap.txt")}' {} +
```

The problem showed up when I try to output to a specific folder

```
BASE="/home/dir/input/"
OUT_FOLDER="/home/dir/output/"
find "$BASE" -type f -iname "*_pv_bind_basefile.txt" -exec awk '{print toupper($0) >> ($OUT_FOLDER FILENAME "_cap.txt")}' {} +
```

I got the following error message

> awk: illegal field $(), name "OUT_FOLDER"  input record number 1, file
>   /home/dir/input/TAB1.a1.001.txt  source line number 1

I tried several iterations to output the files and failed miserably after a few hours...It must be some simple thing that I overlooked or not knowing how to do it. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variables and Awk variables are different things.

If you export a variable to the environment, you can access it via awk's `ENVIRON` array - so you could do (note: I omitted the `find`, since it's not central to the issue)

```
export OUT_FOLDER="/home/dir/output/"
awk '{print toupper($0) >> ENVIRON["OUT_FOLDER"] FILENAME "_cap.txt"}'
```

Alternatively, you can pass variables using the `-v` option

```
OUT_FOLDER="/home/dir/output/"
awk -v out_folder="$OUT_FOLDER" '{print toupper($0) >> out_folder FILENAME "_cap.txt"}'
```

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver it's very helpful. Now I just need to figure out how to add basename command into awk. :D

Comment: @Molly_K you could probably use the awk `split` function to implement a `basename` e.g. `n = split(FILENAME,p,"/"); print p[n]`. But perhaps you should consider use `-execdir` in place of `-exec` in the find command instead.

Comment: Thank you @seeldriver, I followed your suggestion using `split(FILENAME,p."/"); print p[n]`. But I was not able to get it to work. I got the following error message `awk: bailing out at source line 1`. I understand this is not part of the original question, I am happy to open another question if you think that's more appropriate. The full command line I used was ` find "$BASE" -type f -iname "*sefile.txt" -exec awk '{print toupper($0) >> (ENVIRON["OUT_FOLDER"] (n = split(FILENAME,p,"/"); print p[n]) "_cap.txt")}' {} +` I also tried to put split before `print toupper($0)`, also did not work.

Comment: @Molly_K `print p[n]` was just for illustration: to construct a filename from the value you would sue something more like `{n = split(FILENAME,p,"/"); print toupper($0) >> ENVIRON["OUT_FOLDER"] p[n] "_cap.txt"}'. But I recommend you use `-execdir` if possible so that `FILENAME` will be relative to its parent directory instead.

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. I was able to execute the awk command under the proper directory using `-execdir`. Also, moving `n = split(FILENAME,p,"/")` in front of `print toupper` works as well. Thank you very much for the quick response. I read up the man page for find and am continuing my reading on the awk book by Dale Dougherty.